# Prove or disprove my guess

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits

In my textbook there is an exercise about L'Hospital's Rule (LHR for short):

> If $f(x)\in\ C^1 (a,+\infty)$,$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to+\infty}[f(x)+f'(x)]=k\in\mathbb R$, prove :$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=k$
>   Proof:
>   $$\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{e^xf(x)}{e^x}=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{e^xf(x)+e^xf'(x)}{e^x}=\lim_{x\to+\infty}[f(x)+f'(x)]=k$$

Stunning. Isn't it? It's just magical to come up with $1=\frac{e^x}{e^x}$ here. And inspired by this magic, a thought popped up into my mind. I came to ponder on this: will it also be true to say the following?

> If $f(x)\in\ C^1 (a,+\infty)$,$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to+\infty}[f(x)-f'(x)]=k\in\mathbb R$, then $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=k$

Naturally I tried $1=\frac{e^{-x}}{e^{-x}}$ this time. Then I got this
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{e^{-x}f(x)}{e^{-x}}$$
Now if I'm allowed to apply LHR then I'm done. But nobody tells me it is a $\frac00$ pattern. Yet I still don't want to give up on this thought. I think maybe the condition $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to+\infty}[f(x)-f'(x)]=k\in\mathbb R$ will make sure that LHR is appliable here. (In fact I guess $f(x)$ might even bounded here. Just a guess, though, based on nothing reliable) But I get stuck and cannot go any further to prove or disprove the appliability of LHR here. Smart people in this site, please give me some help. Thanks in advance!

---

**SPECIAL EDIT: Clarification about the LHR**
I'm making this edit about LHR because some of you believe that LHR is appliable only for the $\frac00$ and $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ patterns. I'm not being rude but it seems like a major misbelief. I have to clarify here that LHR also works for the $\frac{*}{\infty}$ pattern where $*$ is not necessarily infinity.
Here goes one rigorous statement of LHR:

> **L'Hospital's Rule**
>   Suppose $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are differentialbe on $(a,a+d]$ (where $d>0$), and $g'(x)\ne 0$. If 
>   $$\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to a^+}g(x)=0$$
>   or
>   $$\lim_{x\to a^+} g(x)=\infty,$$
>   and 
>   $$\exists \lim_{x\to a^+} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}\in \mathbb R^{*}$$
>   where $\mathbb R^{*}$ denotes the extended real line, then
>   $$\lim_{x\to a^+}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to a^+}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A disproof is $f(x)=e^x$. $f(x)-f'(x)=0,$ but $f(x)$ has no limit

Comment: I really don't get how OP could miss this counterexample

Comment: Oh yes... I should have realized $e^x$'s invariablity under differenciation.. thank you

Comment: @AnalysisStudent0414. Sorry I was stupid.   Maybe it's because I was too anxious to prove that but thought little about disproving that :)

Comment: @AnalysisStudent0414.  My impression was that the switch from a plus to a minus usually wouldn't make so much difference.  But this time it surely teaches me.

Answer (score 2):

Does the second equality in your proof (for the exercise, not for your conjecture) work for $f(x) = e^{-x}$? Or perhaps I should say "Why does the second equality NOT work?" :)

BTW: I really like this idea -- it is, as you observe, really clever!

Comment: I have checked but I think it does work for $e^{-x}$.

Comment: What you apply LHR, both numerator and denominator need to go to 0 or $\infty$. When $f(x) = e^-x$, the numerator is $e^0 = 1$, but the denominator, $e^x$ goes to infinity. So applying LHR is not allowed. (The conclusion of the alleged theorem still holds...but this argument doesn't *prove* the theorem.)

Comment: I'm sorry but I think I have to point out that when the denominator goes to infinity, the numerator does NOT necessarily go to infinity. ;)

Comment: If you want to apply LHR to $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{u(x)}{v(x)}$, it's essential that either (i) $\lim_{x \to a} u(x) = \lim_{x \to a} v(x) = 0$ or (ii) $\lim_{x \to a} u(x) = \lim_{x \to a} v(x) = \pm \infty$; otherwise you cannot conclude that $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{u(x)}{v(x)} = \lim_{x \to a} \frac{u'(x)}{v'(x)}$. In the example I gave ($f(x) = e^{-x}$), we have $u(x) = 1$ and $v(x) = e^x$; the hypotheses do not hold, so you cannot apply LHR.

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, your question asks for the “why” of a claim that is wrong. The equality holds for $e^{-x}$, since $0=0$. You just can't use LHR to derive or prove it.

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig has said exactly what I was trying to get at...only better. :)

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig。 .... Well I just had the class. I'm sorry I really can't agree with u here. The textbook also gives a rigorous proof.  The two possible cases where LHR is ok to use are lim u=lim v=0 or lim v=infinity.  As for lim u= infinity, it's really not necessary.

Comment: Consider $u(x) = \sin(x), v(x) = x$. The lim of $u/v$ as $x$ approaches $\infty$ is $0$; the limit of $u' / v' = \cos(x)/1$ is undefined. That would appear to contradict your claim, Vim.

Comment: @JohnHughes "Undefined limit" is another story, which means LHR does fail, but **not because** $u(x)$ doesn't go to infinity. Even $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ both go to infinity, LHR failure still can happen. Just think about $u(x)=x+\cos x$ and $v(x)=x+\sin x$ as $x$ goes to infinity. It's a $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ type, but LHR still fails.

Comment: @JohnHughes I'm going to post a rigorous statement of LHR in my edit on this question. You can take a look to see if it's right :)

Comment: @Vim That is not the usual formulation of l'Hospital's rule, see, e.g., http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LHospitalsRule.html or the wikipedia entry. I don't have a counterexample for the extension and it seems plausible; neither do I doubt that including it in the lemma simplifies things. But please don't be surprised if not everyone agrees that your proof directly follows from LHR.

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig。Thank u!  Well, my version is directly copied from my book (with rigorous proof in there) so it is not "plausible " but "reasonable".  And honestly I do get a bit surprised that LHR can have different versions......  But anyhow that doesn't matter since it is not the point of my question ;)

Comment: @Vim If you follow that link, you'll find examples that show that neither your nor the standard formulation is really rigorous and leaves out at least one precondition. Which I don't think I have seen pointed out anywhere else, but the examples make sense and yes, I did miss that point in the proof, come to think of it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = e^x+k$.
Then
$f(x)-f'(x) = k$.